# NSBezierPath does not show

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsbezierpath

I am drawing some rectangles directly on the main window using NSBezierPath. The drawing code is triggered by a button on the main window. If I **click** on the button, the drawing code happens, but the drawing does not show on the window. On the other hand, if I **press** the button's shortcut key, the drawing does show on the window. I have done a lot of trial and error with methods that cause a window or view to refresh, and the same behavior persists. Any thoughts? Many thanks.

Comment: It sounds like you are "fighting the framework".  Normally, you draw when Cocoa asks you to, e.g., in a `drawRect:` method of an `NSView` subclass.  If I've misunderstood, you should show some code.

Comment: You are absolutely right. Now I realize that I should do just that: add a custom view to my main window, and do all my drawing in that view's `-drawRect:`. Thanks so much.